# what is the radial extent of the last scattering "shell"?

Tags: cosmology, cosmic-microwave-background

At CMB recombination (z=1090), what is the radial extent of the last scattering "shell"?
a) Delta(z) = ....
b) Delta(comoving angular distance)= ....Mpc

The WMAP first-year parameters give 
Delta(z) = 195. Is this still correct?

Comment: Welcome to physics.SE! Signatures and personal greetings are not used on SE, so I deleted them from your question.

Comment: See the answer to this question :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114873/the-initial-conditions-of-the-cmb-spectrum/114914#114914